# 3D Barycentric point Intersection

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry, directx, collision

I'm first going to start by saying, yes I have looked for not even days or hours, but literally months in to this problem. I like to tackle my problems head on, but today I'm absolutely stuck.

I'm trying to determine if a point is within a triangle in a 3D space, and I have the following code in place to attempt to detect it.

The test:

```
bool D3DHandler::IsCollidingWithTerrain(D3DXVECTOR3 pos){
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < chunk.at(0).GetWidth()-1; i++){
        for (unsigned int ii = 1; ii < chunk.at(0).GetWidth()-1; ii++){
            if (Physics::PolyPointCollision(
                NORMALVERTEX{ chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii).X, chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii).Y, chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii).Z, { 0, 0, 0 } },
                NORMALVERTEX{ chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i + 1, ii).X, chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i + 1, ii).Y, chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i + 1, ii).Z, { 0, 0, 0 } },
                NORMALVERTEX{ chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii + 1).X, chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii + 1).Y, chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii + 1).Z, { 0, 0, 0 } },
                NORMALVERTEX{ pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, { 0, 0, 0 } })
                ||
                Physics::PolyPointCollision(
                NORMALVERTEX{ chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii).X, chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii).Y, chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii).Z, { 0, 0, 0 } },
                NORMALVERTEX{ chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i - 1, ii).X, chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i - 1, ii).Y, chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i - 1, ii).Z, { 0, 0, 0 } },
                NORMALVERTEX{ chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii - 1).X, chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii - 1).Y, chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii - 1).Z, { 0, 0, 0 } },
                NORMALVERTEX{ pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, { 0, 0, 0 } })){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The function in question:

```
bool Physics::PolyPointCollision(NORMALVERTEX a, NORMALVERTEX b, NORMALVERTEX c, NORMALVERTEX p){
    NORMALVERTEX v0 =  { c.X - a.X, c.Y - a.Y, c.Z - a.Z, { 0, 0, 0 } };
    NORMALVERTEX v1 =  { b.X - a.X, b.Y - a.Y, b.Z - a.Z, { 0, 0, 0 } };
    NORMALVERTEX v2 =  { p.X - a.X, p.Y - a.Y, p.Z - a.Z, { 0, 0, 0 } };
    float dot00 = (v0.X*v0.X) + (v0.Y*v0.Y) + (v0.Z * v0.Z);
    float dot01 = (v0.X*v1.X) + (v0.Y*v1.Y) + (v0.Z * v1.Z);
    float dot02 = (v0.X*v2.X) + (v0.Y*v2.Y) + (v0.Z * v2.Z);
    float dot11 = (v1.X*v1.X) + (v1.Y*v1.Y) + (v1.Z * v1.Z);
    float dot12 = (v1.X*v2.X) + (v1.Y*v2.Y) + (v1.Z * v2.Z);
    float invDenom = 1 / ((dot00*dot11) - (dot01*dot01));
    float u = ((dot11*dot02) - (dot01*dot12))*invDenom;
    float v = ((dot00*dot12) - (dot01*dot02))*invDenom;
    if (u >= 0 && v >= 0 && (v + u)<1){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What I am doing here is converting the 3 points in a mesh for a terrain to be converted in to triangles, then sending that to a function to convert that in to a test to determine if a point is within the triangle using barycentric coordinates. However, it works to an extent, as if I enter the X-Z plane of the triangle, the test will return true, however it does NOT detect anything along the Y axis. My question is how do I get my function to detect the Z axis so I know for certain that the point is within that triangle's bounds in all axis.

Here is a screenshot of the engine I am making with the exact situation I'm trying to explain.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfqnL.png

EDIT:

D3DHandler.h class:

```
class D3DHandler{
public:
    D3DHandler(HWND hWnd,int WINX,int WINY,HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow);
    ~D3DHandler();
    bool IsCollidingWithTerrain(D3DXVECTOR3 pos);
    bool DeviceCheck();
    void UnlockBuffer();
    void LockBuffer();
    void print2DPixel(int x,int y,int r,int g,int b);
    void print2DPixel(int x,int y,D3DCOLOR c);
    void printVertexArray(NORMALVERTEX *vertex,int length);
    void printIndexArray(NORMALVERTEX *vertex,short *indicies,int vLength,int iLength);
    void printVertexArrayWireframe(NORMALVERTEX *vertex,int length);
    void printIndexArrayWireframe(NORMALVERTEX *vertex,short *indicies,int vLength,int iLength);
    void PrepareFrame(Player p);
    void SetupLight();
    void AddObjectToRoom(NORMALVERTEX* model,int mLength,short *modelIndices,int iLength,D3DXCOLOR dCol,D3DXCOLOR aCol);
    void AddObjectToRoom(TEXVERTEX* model,int mLength,short *modelIndices,int iLength,D3DXCOLOR dCol,D3DXCOLOR aCol,int texId);
    void AddObjectToRoom(float xPos,float yPos,float zPos,wchar_t meshName);
    boolean CheckRoom();
    void RenderRoom();
    void RenderTerrain();
    void ClearBuffer();
    void SetRenders();
    void LoadRoom();
    void PresentParams();
    void NewFont(LPCTSTR faceName,int size,int thickness, bool italic);
    IDirect3DDevice9* GetDevice();
    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 grabTexture(int index);
    void PresentFrame();
    D3DMesh* GrabMesh(wchar_t meshName);
    void RenderFont(int fontId,char* text,int x,int y,D3DCOLOR colour,LPD3DXSPRITE sprite,DWORD alignment);
    void ResetDevice(HWND hWnd);
    void RebootDevice(HWND hWnd);
    bool isActive;
private:
    D3DVIEWPORT9        viewPort;
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    D3DRoom *room;
    D3DXMATRIX matRotateX,matRotateY,matRotateZ,matTranslate,matScale,matView,matProjection;
    D3DLIGHT9 light;
    D3DMATERIAL9 material;
    IDirect3D9*         pDirect3D;
    IDirect3DDevice9*   pDevice;
    IDirect3DSurface9*  pBackBuffer;
    D3DLOCKED_RECT      backRect;
    LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 vBuffer;
    LPDIRECT3DINDEXBUFFER9 iBuffer;
    HWND                            hWind;
    std::vector<D3DTerrain>         chunk;
    std::vector<D3DFont>            font;
    std::vector<LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9> texture;
    std::vector<D3DMesh>            mesh;
    int WINX,WINY;

    HINSTANCE hInst;
    HINSTANCE hPrev;
    LPSTR lpCmdLne;
    int nCmdShw;
};
```

D3DTerrain class (it is what the "chunk" is):

```
class D3DTerrain{
public:
    D3DTerrain(float xPos,float yPos,float zPos);
    ~D3DTerrain();
    void Render(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice);
    void Load(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice);
    void Load(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 PDevice,char* fName,wchar_t* tName);
    void Release(){vBuffer->Release();iBuffer->Release();m_texture->Release();m_textureDetail->Release();m_vertecies=NULL;m_indices=NULL;m_height=NULL;}
    TEX2VERTEX GetVertex(unsigned int x,unsigned int y){return m_vertex[x*(int)m_width+y];}
    UINT GetWidth(){return m_width;}
private:
    IDirect3DVertexBuffer9  *vBuffer;
    IDirect3DIndexBuffer9   *iBuffer;
    TEX2VERTEX              *m_vertex;
    UCHAR*                  m_height;
    UINT                    m_vertecies;
    UINT                    m_indices;
    UINT                    m_width;
    char                    m_fileLoc[128];
    wchar_t                 m_textureName[128];
    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9      m_texture,m_textureDetail;
    D3DXMATRIX m_rotX,m_rotY,m_rotZ,m_translate,m_scale,m_textureCords; 
};
```

Vertex types:

```
struct NORMALVERTEX{
    FLOAT X, Y, Z;
    D3DVECTOR NORMAL;
};
struct T_NORMALVERTEX{
    FLOAT X, Y, Z;
    D3DVECTOR NORMAL;
    FLOAT U, V;
};
struct TEXVERTEX{
    FLOAT X, Y, Z;
    FLOAT U, V;
};
struct TEX2VERTEX{
    FLOAT X, Y, Z;
    FLOAT U1, U2, V1, V2;
};
```

*I'm not here for critique on my programming, it's messy as I am only trying to get a major function working and then I will optimize and reorganize my code, it's a personal project, and I know it's rough.*

Comment: Oh, you code is so obfuscated! This is kind of copy-paste oriented programming. Both functions are hairy mess! Switch to object-oriented: introduce some kind of math objects and functions, such as `Vector3f`, `dot()` and `toBarycentric()` to improve readability and make it less error-prone.   I'm sure, that you'll then instantly spot error in debugger. Check [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Comment: A purely algorithmic adaptation of a 3D Point in or *on* a 3D triangle test will be prone to precision limits. You need to fake a 'thickness' of the point or plane with tolerance/epsilon values. Dan Sunday has a site with [algorithms](http://geomalgorithms.com/a04-_planes.html#Barycentric-Coordinate-Compute) for determining points in barycentric coordinates.

Comment: You need to add a test if the point is in the triangle's plane (or at least nearly in the plane). Otherwise, you won't get valid barycentric coordinates. This can be done by calculating the distance of the point from the plane.

Comment: Drop: I wrote this 100% from scratch, there is no syntactic or semantic errors, it's a problem with my algorithm. I was unaware of the toBarycentric() and dot() functions, thank you for showing me. :).
BrettHale: I don't think I understand what you mean, also I've visited that site before and it confused me, as it still does now, can you expand, I woud love it, thanks.
@NicoSchertler How do I go about calculating the distance of the point? I've seen this mentioned before but upon looking up the math it got very confusing.
All: I Will add more of my code to reduce any obfuscation you see.

Comment: @Drop sorry I skimmed your comment, after re-reading I see what you meant. I've not implemented anything to clean up the code such as math functions yet as I am just trying to get functionality working before I clean it all up. The debugger obviously won't show anything, as the return is outputted on to my screen. I've debugged it before too and it will return true regardless of it I am colliding with the space or not, however if on the X-Z plane I am not colliding it will give a notification. Also I am not repeating myself on the first function, as one checks + points and the other - points.

Comment: @GrahamO'Grady The key point of my comment was that you **can not** `get functionality working before clean it all up`. There is too much copy-paste: instead of one `dot(v1, v2)` function, now you need to check each line where you calculating dot product (do you put `y` instead of `x`? `v2` instead `v0`? each line!). And `IsCollidingWithTerrain` is absolutely undebuggable (does all of your `i`s and `ii`s correct? O_O ). You must first clean it up to see what is wrong. Even if your copy-paste is correct everywhere now, re-design will permit you to see algorithm issues cleaner.

Comment: @Drop thank you for your concern but I would like to make a point that I was not focusing on how clean my code was. I have it working now, and now that it is working. I have already debugged with my code and I can find everything, nothing was wrong with my program's semantics or syntax, it was an error involving the actual function. See my reply below to see my new code if you care. I'm not trying to attack you but I would appreciate that you make constructive comments rather than stating the obvious. Thank you however for trying to help me and I appreciate that you make an effort for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so whatever the reason the previous way I approached that was incorrect, so I looked for the mathematical definition of how to find the barycentric coordinates, which involved the vector lengths and the cross product. While the square rooting is slow, it works, I will be tweaking the way this function works in the future and trying to clean and optimize it to my best ability, however this is how I went about fixing this issue.

UtilityFunctions.h

```
#include "DataTypes.h"
namespace Util{
    float map(float in, float minA, float maxA, float minB, float maxB);
    float dot(float ax, float ay, float az, float bx, float by, float bz);
    float dot(Point3D a, Point3D b);
    float length(Point3D p);
    Point3D sub(Point3D a, Point3D b);
    Point3D toBarycentric(Point3D a, Point3D b, Point3D c, Point3D p);
    Point3D cross(Point3D a, Point3D b);
};
```

UtilityFunctions.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "UtilityFunctions.h"

float Util::map(float in, float minA, float maxA, float minB, float maxB){
    float ratio = 0.0f;
    if (abs(maxA - minA)>0){
        ratio = (maxB - minB) / (maxA - minA);
    }
    return (in - minA)*ratio + minB;
}

float Util::dot(float ax, float ay, float az, float bx, float by, float bz){ return (ax*bx) + (ay*by) + (az*bz); }
float Util::dot(Point3D a, Point3D b){ return (a.X*b.X) + (a.Y*b.Y) + (a.Z*b.Z); }
float Util::length(Point3D p){
    return ((p.X*p.X) + (p.Y*p.Y) + (p.Z*p.Z));
}
Point3D Util::cross(Point3D a, Point3D b){
    return{ ((a.Y*b.Z) - (a.Z*b.Y)), ((a.X*b.Z) - (a.Z*b.X)), ((a.X*b.Y) - (a.Y*b.X)) };
}
Point3D Util::sub(Point3D a, Point3D b){
    return{ a.X - b.X, a.Y - b.Y, a.Z - b.Z };
}
Point3D Util::toBarycentric(Point3D a, Point3D b, Point3D c, Point3D p){
    Point3D v0 = sub(c, a);
    Point3D v1 = sub(b, a);
    Point3D v2 = sub(p, a);

    Point3D v12 = cross(v1, v2);
    Point3D v10 = cross(v1, v0);

    if (dot(v12, v10) < 0){ return{ 0, 0, -1 }; }

    Point3D v02 = cross(v0, v2);
    Point3D v01 = cross(v0, v1);

    if (dot(v02, v01) < 0){ return{ 0, 0, -1 }; }

    float denom = length(v01);
    return{ length(v12) / denom, length(v02) / denom, 0 };
}
```

PhysicsFunctions.cpp

```
#include "PhysicsHandler.h"
bool Physics::PolyPointCollision(Point3D a,Point3D b,Point3D c,Point3D p){
    Point3D w = Util::toBarycentric(a, b, c, p);
    if (w.X+w.Y<=1&&w.Z>=0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The topmost function:

```
bool D3DHandler::IsCollidingWithTerrain(D3DXVECTOR3 pos){
    Point3D pointPos = { pos.x, pos.y, pos.z };
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < chunk.at(0).GetWidth() - 1; i++){
        for (unsigned int ii = 1; ii < chunk.at(0).GetWidth() - 1; ii++){
            Point3D originVertex = chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii);
            if (Physics::PolyPointCollision(originVertex,chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i + 1, ii),
                chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii + 1),pointPos)){
                return true;
            }
            if (Physics::PolyPointCollision(originVertex,chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i - 1, ii),
                chunk.at(0).GetVertex(i, ii - 1),pointPos)){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Proof / test results:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/42pcJ.jpg